# Re-initializing a Pointer To Fill an Array: Why?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am working through Dan Gookin's *C Programming for Dummies* and am having trouble understanding the solution to exercise 19-6 why he is re-initializing the pointers.

Here is the original code I was supposed to modify. On line 8 (with the comment) he initializes the pointer `pn` to the array `numbers`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    int x;
    int *pn;

    pn = numbers;       /* initialize pointer */

    /* Fill array */
    for(x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        *pn=x+1;
        pn++;
    }

    /* Display array */
    for(x=0;x<10;x++)
        printf("numbers[%d] = %d\n",
                x,numbers[x]);

    return(0);
}
```

Ok, I'm good so far.

But in the following solution for the exercise I'm having problems with he asked "to make the second `for` loop display the array’s values using the 'peeker' side of pointer variable `pn`" (Peeking is his less technical word for dereferencing which I actually like).

And here is his solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numbers[10];
    int x;
    int *pn;

    pn = numbers;       /* initialize pointer */

/* Fill array */
    for(x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        *pn=x+1;
        pn++;
    }

    pn = numbers;

/* Display array */
    for(x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        printf("numbers[%d] = %d, address %p\n",
                x+1,numbers[x],pn);
        pn++;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

After he fills the array, he re-initializes `pn` to numbers. Why is he doing this? Isn't `pn` pointing to the `numbers` array already? Thus, when he fills it with the values `*pn = x+ 1` at the address `pn` points to (which should be `numbers` right??), why isn't the `numbers` array getting filled? Obviously he needs to do this step because when I take this line out, which I was missing from my original solution, it doesn't work.

I would have never thought of this solution just on my own without looking so now I would like to understand why this re-initializing step.

Comment: Please note that there is no need for this pattern:  `for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { *pn = x + 1; pn++; }`  For loops don't _have to_ start at `0`.  Instead: `for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) { *pn = x; pn++; }` And we can clean this up further by realizing how the post increment operator works:   `for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) { *pn++ = x; }`

Answer (score 2):

`pn++;` increments `pn`. After the loop containing this executes, `pn` no longer points to the beginning of `numbers`; it has been incremented to the end.

Comment: Aw ok I see! Thank you. I have heard incrementing a pointer like this `pn++` is actually not advisable as it is easy to touch memory you shouldn't. What do you think of this?

Comment: @ai88 you can always `pn[x]`

Comment: @0___________: Interesting. I've never seen this notation before. Granted I'm new to C (I only started taking Harvard's Intro to CS in late July). But is this just array notation on a pointer variable?